# Why are applications signed twice for distribution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When you build a project in xcode, you specify the provisioning profile/certificate pair in the build settings, and when exporting an archive, you specify an additional provisioning profile to use. What is the reason for asking for this information twice?

**Edit for clarification:** I've gone through the contents of a bunch of my generated .ipa files, and there seem to be two locations that pertain to signing/provisioning. The document in the  _CodeSign folder (which seems to contain encrypted hashes of the file contents, to verify contents/source), and the .mobileprovision file, which seems like it would be added when the build is exported. At this point in time, I don't see anything that would indicate the purpose of the provisioning profile selected in *build settings*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. When you create a provisioning profile on the developer portal, you specify a specific distribution certificate to use. The provisioning profile only has one certificate...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not actually a programming question.

Comment: @Almo For iOS developers, this is in the category of *practical, answerable problems that are unique to [iOS] software development* and should therefore be considered on-topic.

Comment: Good point. I'll also state that I think the close votes for Server Fault make no sense, either. My close vote is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify a provision profile in the build settings that Xcode uses to sign the app. This makes it possible for you to run your app on a device during development, for example. If I remember correct, in the past the project build settings was the only place where you could specify the profile to use, so you'd typically set the Debug build to use your development profile, and your Release build to use the distribution profile.

At some point (Xcode 4, I think), application archives were introduced to make things easier for developers. You create a single archive and then distribute the app it contains in different ways. You can do an ad hoc distribution to send out to your testers, and then you can use the very same archive to submit to the app store, or create a version for enterprise distribution, depending on the type of program you've joined. But since different distribution methods require different profiles, Xcode asks you for the profile you want to use when you distribute.

Xcode's Archive function is a huge convenience -- it takes a lot of the complexity out of submitting your app, and also takes care of saving the symbols file for each version you distribute so that you can make sense of any crash logs you might receive. It's a recognition of developers' need to use the very same build of an app in different ways. If it seems a little odd that you specify the provision profile to use in two different places, so be it -- that's a rough edge that might get cleaned up in a future Xcode version.

I don't know of any authoritative information on exactly how app signing works, but I *think* it goes like this:

- the provision profile contains your certificate (which includes your public key), and is signed with Apple's private key
- you sign your app with the private key that is the counterpart to the public key in your certificate
- the device uses Apple's public key to authenticate the profile, and then uses your public key from the profile to authenticate the app signature
- if everything matches up, the device will run the app; if not, the app will fail to install

Forget about the "app binary" and "ipa" being signed separately -- I think that's a red herring, and it's unlikely that iOS has to validate two different signatures.

Comment: I plan on doing some additional testing, and what you've said is what I expected (that it's just a rough edge), but if the provisioning profile for the archive can legally change (ie, appstore vs ad-hoc/enterprise) what is the purpose of the provisioning profile specified in build-settings?

To clarify: If the app binary is signed with the provisioning profile in build-settings (rather than just the certificate, as I expected), how does that avoid mismatch issues changing the ipa profile? Or is it ignored?

Comment: @Nyth I've tried to explain a little further in my answer. If there were a possibility for "mismatch issues" you can be sure there'd be a few hundred questions about the resulting errors here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but think - First time xCode sign just binary app, and second time whole .ipa archive.